# How can I access the custom target attribute within material UI select options in React js

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui, onchange

**Here is my select element**

```
<Select
    native 
    onChange={this.handleDepChange}
  >  
     {
      departments.map((dep, index) => (
        <option key={'dep-ind - ' + index} value={dep.id} depCode={dep.code}>
          {dep.name}
        </option>
       ))
     }                                    
</Select>
```

I defined custom attribute within **option element** named **`depCode`**.

**Here is my `onChange` event**

```
handleDepChange = (e) => {
   console.log(e.target.value)   //it give the intended value
   console.log(e.target.depCode) //it is undefined
}
```

Can someone please guide me, how I can access **`depCode`**.
I am using MaterialUI library.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
e.nativeEvent.target.getAttribute("depcode")
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64160047/how-can-i-access-the-custom-target-attribute-within-material-ui-select-options-i]

Comment: hi, i check live demo and use the same code but in my project its returning null.

Comment: i am using class component

Comment: @hafizadeel, you should add a complete [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can know what's wrong with your code. Specifically, make a react file with a component and put everything related to reproduce the error and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Custom attributes should always start with `data-`.

So for example in your case: `data-depcode`:

```
 <option key={'dep-ind - ' + index} value={dep.id} data-depcode={dep.code}>
```

You can then access it like so:

```
handleDepChange = (e) => {
   const depvalue = e.target.dataset.depcode;
   console.log(depvalue);
 }
```

Some more info and examples: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-access-custom-attributes-from-aevent-object-in-react

Comment: hi, i am using same logic in my project, but its still returning undefined, i don't determine where is the problem

Comment: onChange={this.handleDepChange} change that to:  onChange={() => this.handleDepChange()} and else remove the this. also

Comment: onChange={this.handleDepChange()} giving me an error **Cannot read property of target**

Comment: Yeah you should post reproducible code at this point. We're guessing now.